# Bootstrap sass upgrade error. 'border-bottom-right-radius"

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, sass, react-bootstrap

I have upgraded Bootstrap v4 to v5  Now i am getting this error how to solve it?
only  `border-bottom-right-radius` gives me error

./src/index.scss (./node_modules/css-loader/dist/cjs.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-1!./node_modules/postcss-loader/src??postcss!./node_modules/resolve-url-loader??ref--6-oneOf-5-3!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js??ref--6-oneOf-5-4!./src/index.scss)
**@include border-bottom-right-radius(0);**

**Mycode**

```
.card-title {
                background-color: $gray-100;

                @include border-radius($border-radius);
                // @include border-bottom-left-radius(0);
                @include border-bottom-right-radius(0);

                &.collapsed {
                    @include border-radius($border-radius);
                }
            }
```

Comment: `border-bottom-start-radius` and `border-bottom-end-radius` have replaced left and right

Comment: omg ,i have been trying for whole day, thanks!

Comment: please post it as answer and mark the question as solved

Comment: how to do that i don't know

Answer (score 0):

`border-bottom-start-radius` and `border-bottom-end-radius` have replaced left and right –